# Creating multiple buffers in a loop in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, loop

I would like to do 50 buffers from a known point. I know to do one by one, but I would like to do in a Loop. Is there any way to do it?

This is part of my code:

```
var buff1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-46.633286, -23.550510]).buffer(1000);

var buff...n= ee.Geometry.Point([-46.633286, -23.550510]).buffer(...n);

var buff50= ee.Geometry.Point([-46.633286, -23.550510]).buffer(50000);

var interval = 1000;

var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: [buff1, buff...n, buff50],
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});

Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: ['red']}, 'buff1');
```

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_js_03#for-loops

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the loop. You can generate a distance list and use `map` function on it.

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-46.633286, -23.550510]);

// generate a buffer distance list
var distance_list = ee.List.sequence({start:1000, end:50000, step:1000});

var buffer_func = function (distance) {
    // new feature containing the buffer
    return ee.Feature(point.buffer(distance), {});
}

var buffers = ee.FeatureCollection(distance_list.map(buffer_func));

var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: buffers,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});

Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: ['red']}, 'buff1');
```

[image]